# Using custom icon assets with DesktopAppConverter UWP

Tags: wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I'm using DesktopAppConverter to convert my WPF application into a windows store compatible app. Right now I'm able to get the AppX built but the problem is to do with my application assets.

At the moment, DesktopAppConverter is taking my existing Icon (which looks great in WPF) and using it to somehow create all the different Assets at different resolutions for the UWP app. The icons it creates are coming out looking terrible, really blocky and clearly upscaled.

The way I'm looking at it is that there's 2 options.

1 - I specify a really large Icon file in my WPF app that might somehow end up being scaled better inside DesktopAppConverter. The problem here is that with a large resolution Ico file, I end up with a crazy large file (Ico's don't compress very well from what I understand).

2 - I specify a folder of correctly scaled assets (created using UWP Tile Generator) when building through DesktopAppConverter. This is what I'd like to do. I don't really want to be tweaking my Assets every time.

The 3rd choice is the one I'm heading towards, but don't really want to do. It involves building with AppX, then replacing the assets, then using MakeAppX, then re-signing with the SignTool. All of that seems really unnecessary, so I'm hoping someone from MSFT can let me know I'm missing something fundamental.

Thanks.

Comment: I've asked a similar question: [Fixing scaled images in AppX manifest generated by Destop App Converter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42162466/850848) (still no relevant answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to handle the visual assets for your app package is to use the package manifest editor in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

To use it for your converted app, create an empty UWP project and add the output of the conversion (incl. your appx manifest) in this project. Now you can use the editor to manage the visual assets, build your packages for store submission and much more.

Here is a document that describes the process:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to set up a one-click build process so when I release an update I can easily get it on the store. If I mess around with the files in VS2017 every time, that'll be time consuming. Is there any easy way to automate this?

Comment: You should only have to do all the setup steps once (I know it's a lot of steps ...). Once you have done it, the same build automation approach as for UWPs should apply. Take a look at this document. Please start a new question for any issues around this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps